# How to apply styles to the whole silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have created two different grid background and radio button style in my

```
App.xaml.
```

User can select any style to change the look of the page i.e: Changing the background and style of the radiobutton.

Now When I click on the raduio button the application navigates to another page and the style disappears.

Is there a way to Set the style in application level or I  need to store the `styleVar` as Global Var and check on the second page load and then apply the styles as per the `styleVar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes like Jeff Wilcox said *Implicit styling* is a new thing in Silverlight 4. So if you want to create a style that is the default for all the controls of that type in the range XAML file or the whole application if placed in App.xaml you would leave out the x:Key attribute.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
```

To use ButtonStyle you would have to write:

```
<Button Content="A button" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
```

Leaving out the x:Key would allow you to use ButtonStyle as default.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">

<Button Content="A button with style that has no x:Key value" />
```

Now if you'd need to create a button that doesn't have this default style, you can set the Style property of that button to be x:Null or override by setting a named style to that button.

```
 <Button Content="Default Silverlight button" Style="{x:Null}"/>
```

Another new thing with Styles in Silverlight 4 is that you can create new styles that are based on existing ones. Although it wasn't your question I'll give an example:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BasedStyle}">
```

About implicit styling in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style%28VS.95%29.aspx

**Implicit Styles**

> In Silverlight 4, you can set styles
>   implicitly. That is, you can apply a
>   certain style to all elements of a
>   certain type. When a  resource
>   is declared without an x:Key value,
>   the x:Key value assumes the value of
>   the TargetType property. If you set
>   the style implicitly, the style is
>   applied only to the types that match
>   the TargetType exactly and not to
>   elements derived from the TargetType
>   value. For example, if you create a
>   style implicitly for all the
>   ToggleButton controls in your
>   application, and your application has
>   ToggleButton and CheckBox controls
>   (CheckBox derives from ToggleButton),
>   the style is applied only to the
>   ToggleButton controls.

**BasedOn Styles**

> Starting with Silverlight 3, it is
>   possible to build a new style based on
>   an existing style. You can do this
>   using the BasedOn property. This
>   reduces the duplication of code and
>   makes it easier to manage resources.
>   Each style supports only one BasedOn
>   style. For more information, see the
>   BasedOn property.

Answer (score 2):

Just leave off the x:Key part of the Style, inside App.xaml. This is a new feature for Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 0):

Place the styles in question in the `App.xaml` file.  The application objects Resources property makes Styles and other resources available across the entire application.

Comment: Yes, I am able to set the styles by doing:
radioBtn.Style = (Style)(Application.Current.Resources["rdbFolder"]);

But I have to repeat the process in all the pages to set the style.

Instead I want When I say set the style of the radioBtn on the 1st Page , Itshould be applied to all the radiobuttons in all the pages through out the application.